# Plotting complex functions

Tags: matlab, plot

How to plot complex functions in Matlab? For example:

```
Y[e^jx] = 1 / (1 - cosx + j4)
```

I tried some code, but I think the right way is by plotting real and imaginary part separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 1e3);
y = 1./(1 - cos(x) + i*4);

% Plot absolute value and phase
figure;
subplot(2,1,1); plot(x, abs(y));
subplot(2,1,2); plot(x, angle(y));

% Plot real and imaginary parts
figure;
subplot(2,1,1); plot(x, real(y));
subplot(2,1,2); plot(x, imag(y));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some MATLAB functions that are specific to plotting complex maps:

```
z = cplxgrid(60);
cplxmap(z, 1./(1 - cos(z) + 4*i));
```

See also [Functions of Complex Variables in MATLAB's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/cplxdemo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not for you, but for other people looking to draw complex functions.
We set up a website where you can render them quickly and download them (reflex4you.com, reflex = representation of complex function)

I can display complex functions in 2D in a colorful way. Your function can be 
[visible here](http://www.reflex4you.com/?name=.formula&formula=1%2F(1%20-%20cos(z)%20%2B%20i*z)) and below:

Note that the black is zero, the white infinite, and it covers the complex plane with colors associated to complex numbers, such as red = 1, cyan = -1, i = greenish, -i = purplish.

[image: Reflex of the function he asked.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following:

- `plot(real(Y))`
- `plot(imag(Y))`
- `plot(real(Y),imag(Y))`
- `plot(abs(Y))`

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(re(Y),im(Y))
```

but remember there is a domain associated with a complex function in which it is valid, in your case: cos(x)-4j < 1

Answer (score 0):

By default, `plot(X)` will plot real vs imaginary, so it's equal to `plot(real(X), imag(X))`
For example, try:

```
>> r = sort(rand(10, 1)) + 1i * rand(10, 1);
>> figure, plot(r)
```

If you need them both on y-axis, use:

```
plot([real(X), imag(X)])
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for Python, you can use a tool I wrote: [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot). It uses [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) for complex plotting, i.e., it associated the absolute value of `f(z)` with the brightness and the hue with the complex angle.

Your function:

```py
import cplot
import numpy as np

plt = cplot.plot(lambda z: 1 / (1 - np.cos(z) + 4j), (-10, +10, 400), (-10, +10, 400))
plt.show()
```

[image]